# jQuery Notification plugin on-demand function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, notify

Please view my **[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/7GRdn/embedded/result/)**...

There's a notification bar that comes up. When I use this plugin where I got it ([here](http://www.greepit.com/notify/)), the plugin works great. There's really no documentation on this and I've gotten it installed and working - half way.

When the notification bar is closed, there's an arrow that's supposed to drop down to re-initiate it with a click. I can see the shadow from the arrow there, but it's not coming down.

Not sure how to make it pull down automatically as the author displays **[here](http://www.greepit.com/notify/)**

**This is the script used to call the function...**

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.notification.ondemand').notify();
            $('.button').click(function () {
                $('.notification').removeClass('hide').addClass('hide').removeClass('visible');
                $('.notification.' + $(this).attr('id') + '').notify({ type: $(this).attr('id') });

            });

        });
```

The drop-down arrow works on the demo, but not my site.

Can you please take a look?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the site demo where do you get the code; in the site example there is a buttonset with class `.button` that switch the notify behaviour by using the id of the cicked button:

```
$('.notification.' + $(this).attr('id') + '').notify({ type: $(this).attr('id') });
```

You don't have that button so you can use directly your needed notify type.

The possible values for `type` option are:

- sticky
- floated
- fixed
- ondemand

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.notification.ondemand').notify({ type: 'ondemand' });    
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/qYsfD/

Comment: If I can help you, I'm here :-)